# Example of a function discontinuous in $x_0$ with $ \lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} f'(x) = M$ that is not derivable in $x_0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

I have proven that if $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continues function and
derivable on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{x_0\}$ with
$\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} f'(x) = B$, then f is derivable in $x_0$. My proof uses L'Hôpital's Rule and the assumption that f is continues. Now I am asked, is this still true that f is derivable in
$x_0$ if the assumption of continuity is relaxed. I can not prove this and I have a feeling that it is not true. I am, therefore, looking for a counter example.

Can anyone help me find one example of a function that is derivable everywhere execpt $x_0$ and fulfils $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} f'(x) = B$, but is not derivable in $x_0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function can never be differentiable but non-continuous at any point.

Define a function by $f(x)=1$ everywhere except at $x=0$ and $f(0)=0$ to get your required counterexample.

Comment: Agreed, but the function must fulfil $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} f' = B$. I am wondering if this forces the function to be continuous. So that you need not make the assumption that it is.

Comment: @HaakonA Yes, the function of course satisfies $f^{\prime}(x)=0$ everywhere except at $x=0$ and $\lim_{x\to 0}f^{\prime}(x)=0$.

Comment: Is your $B$ some specific nuber? Then take $f(x)=Bx$ everywhere except at $x=0$, and $f(0)=A$ where $A\neq 0$.

Comment: Ok yes, true. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If a function is differentiable at a point, it must be continuous at that point.

The [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) is an easy counterexample to your claim. Derivative is $0$ everywhere except at $0$ where it does not exist (at least not in the context of functions, although you could claim the delta function to be the everywhere-defined derivative in the context of distributions).

Comment: But does the step function satisfy $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} f' = B$?

Comment: Of course, it's always $0$ at every other point so you trivially have $\lim_{x\to x_0}f'=0$